# In Skyrim only 2 out of 4 enchantments are shown in Active Effects

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I wanted to cast free destruction spells, so I enchanted 4 items with -27% destruction spell cost, but it seems it shows only 2 of the 4 enchantments in the active effects.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSQpY.jpg).

Comment: This is a pretty obvious troubleshoot but you are wearing all of the enchanted equipment, right?

Comment: The last image in your imgur link leads me to believe you're using [SkyUI](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12604). It's probably a graphical bug within the mod. Can you verify all the Fortify Destruction effects are shown when launching Skyrim normally?

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this with no mods and see if they work.

Something strikes me as odd. The enchantments are in pure, proper English but the rest of the game is obviously French.

I'm guessing there may be mod language incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible this is simply a graphical glitch in the Active Effects menu.

Try equipping all four pieces of enchanted equipment and compare the results of a spell cast to the results received from only wearing two.